# Using class encoding for prediction?

Tags: python, data-science, random-forest, one-hot-encoding

I was wondering if you can use class encoding, specifically OneHotEncoder in Python, for prediction, if you do not know all the future feature values?

To give more context. I am predicting whether or not a fine will be paid in the future based upon the location, issuing office & amount (and potentially other features if I can get it to work). When I do onehotencoding on my training set it works great (For 100k rows of data my test accuracy is around 92%, using a 75/25 split).

However, when I then introduce the new data, there are locations and 'offices' the encoder never saw. Therefore, new features were not created. This means that in my training set, I had 2302 columns when I built my model (random forest), while when predicting using the real data, I have 3330 columns, therefore, the model I built is no longer valid. (note, I am also looking at other models as the data is so sparse)

How do you handle such a problem when class encoding? Can you only class encode if you have tight control on your future feature values?

Any help would be much appreciated. Apologies if my terminology is wrong, I am new to this and this is my first post on stackoverflow.

I can add code if it helps however I think it is more the theory which is relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to keep in mind when using OneHotEncoding.

1. The number of classes in a column is important. If a class is missing from the test set but present in the train set, it won't be a problem. But if a class is missing from the train set and present in the test set, the encoding will not be able to recognize the new class. This seems to be the problem in your case.
2. Secondly, you should use the same encoder to encode the train and test split. This way the number of columns in the train and test splits will be the same (`2302 != 3330 columns`), but in the case of any additional classes in the test set, the user can specify how to deal with missing values. Have a look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.__init__).

A possible way to deal with your issue would be to do the OneHotEncoding on the entire dataset and then split the data 75/25. This will work considering you wont have any new training data later.